# Capture Countdown or Tick Event - Threading.Timer C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I have developed a program using `Threading.Timer` to call a method after 30 seconds.

The method is getting called, it's working but I want to get the event so that I can know how many seconds are left out of 30 sec.

I need a kind of tick event which gets fired every seconds. So that I can show the remaining seconds as well. This is my code:

```
Timer timerObj;

timerObj = new Timer(UpdateUI, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
timerObj.Change(30000, Timeout.Infinite);


public void UpdateUI(object state)
{
    ShowQR= false;
}
```

How can I get countdown even ?

Comment: Maybe add a `Stopwatch` to keep track of elapsed time and another `Timer` that fires once a second or so? Then that timer's handler can use the `Stopwatch` to determine elapsed time, and hence the remaining time.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Your idea seems great. Can you please write it so that would be easy for me to add.

Comment: You can also use that same timer you have now (but with 1 second tick), and update UI not on every tick but when elaplsed time exceeds 30 seconds.

Comment: Actually I prefer Evk's suggestion - it avoids having two timers.

Comment: Measure elapsed time with a clock, DateTime.UtcNow is fine.  You only need a timer to refresh the UI.  Its interval is not critical, 100 msec is a decent choice.  Better than 1 sec, that tends to put Nyquist's Sampling Theorem to the test.  And use the correct *kind* of timer to update UI, like System.Windows.Forms.Timer or DispatcherTimer, so you don't have to battle thread-safety issues.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thank you. Could you please write it so that will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you'd go about implementing Evk's suggestion:

```
Timer timerObj;
Stopwatch stopwatch;

...

timerObj = new Timer(UpdateUI, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
timerObj.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

public void UpdateUI(object state)
{
    if (stopwatch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
       {
         timerObj.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
         return;
       }
        
    stopwatch.Restart();    
    ShowQR= false;
}
```

Note how you start the `Stopwatch` at the same time as you call `timerObj.Change()` to start the timer running.

Also note how the timer is set to fire every second rather than every 30s.

Then in the timer handler, you simply check the elapsed time on the `Stopwatch` - if it's less that 30s then just return; otherwise, do the thing you want to do every 30s and (IMPORTANT!) restart the `Stopwatch`.